# Traveling to Corsica from mainland France - will they check my vaccination certificate?

Tags: corsica

I am planning to go from mainland France to Corsica. Will they check my vaccination certificate when entering Corsica from mainland France? As it is the same administrative region I am unsure if they would also check my vaccination certificate again.

Answer (score 2):

Taking any kind of long-distance public transport that is not metropolitan (like TGV, Plane...) is conditioned by the presentation of the `pass vaccinal`

So, yes, when you're going to take your return flight/ferry, they'll check your `pass vaccinal`

Comment: Your answer would be more valuable if it included a source or sources for this assertion.